# ¿Por qué se hizo tan lento mi algoritmo al calcular la desviación estándar usando np.std?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, numpy

Hace poco pregunte como podía mejorar la velocidad de cálculo en un programa que determinaba la media de n periodos dentro de una lista, mejoraba el mio muchisimas veces, estoy usando ese mismo algoritmo y la idea general (o eso creo yo) para calcular ahora otro factor que es: valor medio + (n desviaciones * desviación estandar de valor medio) y la velocidad bajo muchisimo, estoy usando np.std para calcular la desviación.

Este es el código que calcula el valor medio en n periodos:

```
from random import uniform
from time import time


cierre = []
for i in range(1000000):
    cierre.append(uniform(1, 2))

tiempo_inicial = time()
periodos = 20
suma = sum(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
sma = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [suma/periodos]

for i in range (periodos+1, len(cierre)):
    suma = suma - cierre[i - periodos] + cierre[i]
    sma.append(suma/periodos)

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial

print(tiempo_total)
```

Para 1 millon de valores tarda 0.76 segundos

Ahora esta es mi re-implementación con el calculo de las desviaciones estandar y el factor que comenté arriba:

```
from random import uniform
from time import time
import numpy as np 

cierre = []
for i in range(1000000):
    cierre.append(uniform(1, 2))

tiempo_inicial = time()

periodos = 20
desviaciones = 2

suma = sum(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
desv = np.std(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
media = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [suma/periodos]
alta = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [(suma/periodos) + (desviaciones * desv)]
baja = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [(suma/periodos) - (desviaciones * desv)]

for i in range (periodos+1, len(cierre)):
    suma = suma - cierre[i - periodos] + cierre[i]
    desv = np.std(cierre[i+1 - periodos:i + 1])
    media.append(suma/periodos)
    alta.append((suma/periodos) + (desviaciones * desv))
    baja.append((suma/periodos) - (desviaciones * desv))

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial
print(tiempo_total)
```

Para 1 millón de datos tarda 58.43 segundos ¡muchisimo! ¿Cómo fue que lo descompuse? o bajo la lógica que seguí es normal ese tiempo. yo pensaba que el tiempo sería a lo mucho 3 veces más que el primer calculo, pero no fue así.

Incluso mi algoritmo pasado y que pienso es muy malo igualo el tiempo:

```
from random import uniform
from time import time
import numpy as np 

cierre = []
for i in range(1000000):
    cierre.append(uniform(1, 2))

tiempo_inicial = time()

sma = []
alta = []
baja = []
periodos = 20
desviaciones = 2
lista_inicial = []

for i in range(len(cierre)):
    if i > periodos:
        del lista_inicial[0]
        lista_inicial.append(cierre[i])
        media = sum(lista_inicial) / periodos
        desviacion_estandar = np.std(lista_inicial)
        sma.append(media)
        alta.append(media + (desviaciones * desviacion_estandar))
        baja.append(media - (desviaciones * desviacion_estandar))

    elif i < periodos:
        sma.append(cierre[periodos])
        alta.append(cierre[periodos])
        baja.append(cierre[periodos])
    else:
        for j in range(i, i - periodos, -1):
            lista_inicial.append(cierre[j])
        lista_inicial.reverse()
        media = sum(lista_inicial) / len(lista_inicial)
        desviacion_estandar = np.std(lista_inicial)
        sma.append(media)
        alta.append(media + (desviaciones * desviacion_estandar))
        baja.append(media - (desviaciones * desviacion_estandar))

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial

print(tiempo_total)
```

¿En que fallé?

Gracias

Comment: El gran problema creo que está en el cálculo de la desviación estandar en si. Si yo ejecuto tu código obtengo un tiempo de **41.44 s** de los cuales **40.07 s** se deben exlusivamente a `sp.std()` (el calculo de la media y crear las 3 listas de 1 millón de elementos solo conlleva **1.37 s**).  Ten en cuenta que calculas 1 millon de desviaciones y eso cuesta. Un problema es que calculas la media dos veces, seria bueno poder usar la media en `np.std()` pero por desgracia no admite este parámetro. Se podria intentar crear una función a medida para calcular la std específicamente para tu caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, siempre me ayudas mucho, ya corregí el calculo de la media dos veces, gane unos segundos con eso, estuve probando otras librearias de calculo de la desviación pero con malos resultados, `statistics.pstdev()` es 10 veces más lento que `np.std`. Por el momento estoy trabajando en un i3 y 4 gb de ram, supongo que cuándo pase al servidor en donde alojaré la aplicación ganaré bastante tiempo. Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Si, de lo primero que me acordé fue de `statistics.pstdev()` ya que permite pasarle la media, si la tienes ya calculada, como segundo parámetro, pero basta con hacer algunos test para ver que es muy inferior en rendimiento a `np.std()` como bién dices. Creo que tengo una alternativa que te podría valer intentando calcular la desviacíon usando la media que ya tenemos por nosotros mismos, voy a crear una respuesta explicandolo a ver si te vale. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como es lógico para calcular la desviación estándar necesitamos la media. Este método calcula eficientemente la media para tu caso particular pero el problema es que `numpy.std()` no admite que le pasemos la media que eficientemente ya tenemos calculada y la vuelve a calcular, lo cual es una redundancia que no queremos.

Como tu mismo comentas existe `statistics.pstdev()` en la biblioteca estandar de Python que si permite pasarle como segundo parámetro la media precalculada, pero al ser mucho más lenta que  `numpy.std()` no ganamos nada, incluso perdemos tiempo.

Como te comenté la solución estaría en calcular la desviación estándar nosotros mismos para usar la media que ya tenemos. Encontré una posible solución usando `NumPy`.

Sabemos que la desviación estándar no es mas que la raiz cuadrada de la varianza. La varianza es la media de las diferencias con la media elevadas al cuadrado. Pues bién `Numpy` puede hacer esto muy eficiente. Si tenemos la media y el array podemos calcular las diferencias como:

> dif = numpy.array - media

Para calcular los cuadrados y su suma eficientemente podemos usar [`numpy.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> cuadrados_dif = numpy.dot(dif, dif)

Ahora calculamos la media de los cuadrados de las diferencias dividiendo por el numero de elementos (en tu caso es la variable `periodos`) y calculamos la raiz cuadrada (usando `math.sqrt()` o elevando a 0.5).

Quedaria así tu código:

```
from random import uniform
from time import time
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

cierre = []
for i in range(1000000):
    cierre.append(uniform(1, 2))

tiempo_inicial = time()

periodos = 20
desviaciones = 2

suma = sum(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
desv = np.std(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
media = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [suma/periodos]
alta = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [(suma/periodos) + (desviaciones * desv)]
baja = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [(suma/periodos) - (desviaciones * desv)]

for i in range (periodos+1, len(cierre)):
    suma = suma - cierre[i - periodos] + cierre[i]
    med = suma/periodos
    aux = np.array(cierre[i+1 - periodos:i + 1]) - med
    desv = sqrt(np.dot(aux, aux)/periodos)
    media.append(med)
    alta.append(med + (desviaciones * desv))
    baja.append(med - (desviaciones * desv))

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial
print(tiempo_total)
```

El tiempo para mi se reduce de 41.28 segundos a 8.96 segundos para un array de 1 millón de enteros y pasa de 416.65 segundos a 90.25 segundos para uno de 10 millones, lo cual representa una reducción del tiempo del **78%**. Creo que matemáticamente no he metido la pata, he comparado algunas salidas al azar y ambos códigos dan el mismo resultado, pero comprueba los resultados usando el mismo array de partida por ti mismo... :)

Comment: ¡Eres una máquina! muchas gracias, no conocía esa función de np.dot

Answer (score 2):

El problema surge con el `for` que en Python es lento. Normalmente, *numpy* se usa para poder usar operaciones vectorizadas que permiten evitar el uso de bucles.

He hecho una versión vectorizada de tu problema, el cual no entiendo muy bien porque los índices me parecen desplazados, y la he comparado con la tuya inicial. La diferencia en tiempo de cálculo es abismal y los resultados parecen similares.

Uso `np.random.uniform` en lugar de `random.uniform` y la semilla la puedes eliminar (`np.random.seed`), solo es para poder reproducir los ejemplos.

```
from random import uniform
from time import time
import numpy as np 

cierre = np.random.uniform(1, 2, 1000000)

tiempo_inicial = time()

periodos = 20
desviaciones = 2

suma = sum(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
desv = np.std(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
media = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [suma/periodos]
alta = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [(suma/periodos) + (desviaciones * desv)]
baja = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [(suma/periodos) - (desviaciones * desv)]


def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

sumaarr = np.sum(rolling_window(cierre[2:], 20), axis=1)
desvarr = np.std(rolling_window(cierre[2:], 20), axis=1)

mediaarr = np.append(media, sumaarr/periodos)
altaarr = np.append(alta, (sumaarr/periodos) + (desviaciones * desvarr))
bajaarr = np.append(baja, (sumaarr/periodos) - (desviaciones * desvarr))

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial
print(tiempo_total)

######################################################################


tiempo_inicial = time()

periodos = 20
desviaciones = 2

suma = sum(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
desv = np.std(cierre[1:periodos + 1])
media = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [suma/periodos]
alta = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [(suma/periodos) + (desviaciones * desv)]
baja = [cierre[periodos]] * periodos + [(suma/periodos) - (desviaciones * desv)]

for i in range (periodos+1, len(cierre)):
    suma = suma - cierre[i - periodos] + cierre[i]
    desv = np.std(cierre[i+1 - periodos:i + 1])
    media.append(suma/periodos)
    alta.append((suma/periodos) + (desviaciones * desv))
    baja.append((suma/periodos) - (desviaciones * desv))

tiempo_total = time() - tiempo_inicial
print(tiempo_total)

######################################################################

print(mediaarr[-5:])
print(media[-5:])
print(altaarr[-5:])
print(alta[-5:])
print(bajaarr[-5:])
print(baja[-5:])
```

En la primera parte está tu código vectorizado. Los resultados los guardo en las variables `nombreloqueseaarr`.
En la segunda parte estú tu código original. Los resultados se guardan en las variables `nombreloquesea`
En la tercera parte del código se comparan resultados.

Un ejemplo de la salida es:

```
0.4660000801086426
23.439000129699707
[ 1.35230779  1.31052786  1.30012336  1.30526097  1.35144369]
[1.3523077875441034, 1.3105278577699528, 1.3001233584787273, 1.3052609662130137,
 1.3514436884966892]
[ 1.81071186  1.70910241  1.71348813  1.72520832  1.82857868]
[1.8107118591261553, 1.7091024102156576, 1.7134881323550406, 1.7252083196496959,
 1.8285786831530464]
[ 0.89390372  0.91195331  0.88675858  0.88531361  0.87430869]
[0.89390371596205154, 0.91195330532424823, 0.88675858460241397, 0.88531361277633
147, 0.87430869384033194]
```

Donde la primera línea es el tiempo de la primera parte, la segunda línea es el tiempo de la segunda parte y el resto son resultados con ambas porciones de código para ver si los resultados son similares.

P.D.: La función `rolling_window` la he sacado de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811241/5216568) pero *pandas* tiene mucha funcionalidad [*rolling*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) que te permite abordar estos problemas de forma sencilla.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido bastante las funcionalidades rolling

Comment: Ya lo estuve probando es brutal la mejora en los tiempos, no sabía nada acerca de rolling window, si quisiera aprender de eso ¿cómo podría hacerlo? ¿que tengo que saber antes o que puedo leer?

Comment: Una rolling window no es nada especial. Solo aplicas las operaciones a ventanas de datos, no hay mucho que leer. SI haces cálculos de ese tipo numpy te vale pero pandas ya la trae de serie.